# Python ffmpeg subprocess makes unplayable file, but is right size, and just hangs

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I currently have this subprocess calling ffmpeg.

```
print("Starting alphamerge")
cmd = "ffmpeg -y -nostats -loglevel 0 -i %s -i %s -filter_complex '[1][0]scale2ref[mask][main];[main][mask]alphamerge' -c:v qtrle %s" % (
            file_path, temp_file, output)
process = sp.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print('after call')

if stderr:
   return "ERROR: %s" % stderr.decode("utf-8")
print("Process finished")
```

But the process ends up making a file over 2 gigs, unplayable, and just hangs.  It never prints "Process finished", "after call", or an error, it just hangs.

Am I calling subprocess with ffmpeg wrong?

Comment: For testing: **1.** remove `-nostats -loglevel 0`. **2.** Remove: `shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE`. **3.** Execute: `sp.run(shlex.split(cmd))`. I think you are filling your disk because the `qtrle` codec is almost uncompressed.

Comment: Does the same `ffmpeg` command work if you run it unscripted in a command-line interface?

Comment: @llogan it appears not, it isfrom this question, https://superuser.com/questions/1647590/have-ffmpeg-merge-a-matte-key-file-over-the-normal-video-file-removing-the-backg @rotem after I tweaked it it is outputting `Past duration 0.815666 too large
    Last message repeated 1 times
` a bunch, and then freezes when it gets to 0.8156 with or without python.

Comment: @llogan seems it works for smaller videos, so I feel the video must be corrupeted, but the original video and the matte both play

Comment: tried adding `-async 1 -vsync 1` but did not work

Comment: @nadermx Without the command and the log all I can suggest is that you try a more recent version of ffmpeg (ideally from the git master branch) before doing anything else. Since I'm guessing you're using Ubuntu you can [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) it or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: @llogan upgrading ffmpeg fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update your `ffmpeg`

When encountering issues with `ffmpeg` the first step is to try the most recent version. Ideally from the current git master branch. Development is very active and you may be encountering a bug that is already fixed.

See [compile guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) or the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to executables.